# Catch MS Access Append Warning and put information in separate MsgBox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am currently working on a MS Access Database. This DB includes an import from Excel which I execute with a linked Excel sheet and an append query. I like the append warning you get before you start the import, e.g. with the number of rows you are going to append. I would like to keep this information but my end users are somewhat technophobe and the message looks quite scary and severe.

Is there any way to e.g. take the information about how many rows are going to be added and put them into a separate message box? This way I could make it less scary but keep this final check before irreversible changes are made.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the warnings, you can use:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
```

before the append and reset it after:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Then, before the append, count the records with a simple select query:

```
DCount("*", "YourQuery")
```

and use that figure in your custom less scary message.